# Simplifying many possibilities in c# indexof condition

Tags: c#

Is there any way to simplify this code? The input is a string.

```
private string IfItIsPicture(string URI_obrazku)
    {
        if (URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".jpg") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".png") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".bmp") > -1 ||
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".tiff") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".tif") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".jpeg") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".jpg") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".svg") > -1 || 
            URI_obrazku.IndexOf(".gif") > -1)
            { ... some code }
        return someString;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. You might get better answers on StackExchange's [Code-Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for this specific question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on  Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get just the extension. Then check whether that extension is in your collection of known extensions.

```
private string IfItIsPicture(string URI_obrazku)
{
    var knownExtensions = new [] { ".jpg",".png",".bmp", "..."};
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(URI_obrazku);

    if (knownExtensions.Contains(extension, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // ... some code
    }

    return "someString";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq:

```
var types = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".png", ... };

if (types.Any(t => URI_obrazku.IndexOf(t) >= 0))
{
     return someString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an *array*

```
var values = new [] { ".jpg",".png",".bmp", ...};

if(values.Any(x => URI_obrazku.EndsWith(x)))
```

Comment: Maybe it is solves the issue, but it is not semantically the same.

Comment: I would bet that this is the desired semantics and the question got it wrong.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan not semantically the same but I think this is what is intended

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is *better*, but I bet it's faster since it isn't doing multiple IndexOfs:

```
private bool IsPicture(string URI_obrazku)
{
    String Extension = Path.GetExtension(URI_obrazku);

    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".jpg": return true;
        case ".png": return true;
        // other extensions
        default: return false;
    }
}
```